# ubuntu internet problem lag and slow

Tags: networking, internet, browser

My ubuntu internet connection is lagging and slow and in the browser when I open a website it shows a message

```
internet connection is interrupted
```

After I reload again website opens but

[image: like this image]

I have this issue more than two months, I tried every solution on the internet but nothing worked for me.

Please help me in solving this issue

Thank YOu

Comment: There may be a ton of reasons why an internet connection is slow. Most of them unrelated to Ubuntu. There is absoltely no information that would allow to suggest anything.

Comment: Very simple debug is to run `ping namecheap.com` and watch if connection is indeed interrupted.